# position:fixed navigation header overlapping browser scroll bar when using overflow-x

Tags: html, css, web

I'm working on developing a website but I'm facing an issue.

I'm creating a navigational bar which works 90% - there is just a little issue. When a user scrolls to a certain distance, the navigational bar becomes 'stuck' to the page, scrolling with the user. When the navigational bar is 'stuck', it overlaps the main browser bar.

I'm not too sure why this happens, but I believe that the div above it might be causing the issue.

Ignore the icons to the right of the page, windows eight.[image: Navigation bar]

Here's the whole page and stylesheet: https://gist.github.com/TaylerKing/7977e60099c3726938fb

Excuse me for the rusty styling, haven't done pure web design for a year or two;)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 1. Please use http://jsfiddle.net or another website, so that you can post a live version of the problem online, so we don't have to download the file to view it. 2. Also, you should be able to demonstrate the problem without having 129 lines of code. We would be glad to help answer the question, but you need to do preferably both of those things to show you are adequately trying to solve the problem. We aren't here to debug for you, so that is why you should take at least one of these extra steps for this type of question. :)

Comment: @GeorgeBailey http://jsfiddle.net/J7sxD/ I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, posting a live sample is much more convenient, so I can Inspect Element and see what is going on. If you have not used it yet, I recommend you try it, it allows you to disable CSS rules one at a time to narrow down problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of `overflow-x:hidden`, combined with the navigation bar that is `position:fixed`. Using `position:fixed` in unusual situations like this is not as well supported as you might expect.

An alternative would be to use `position:relative`, and have JavaScript update the `top` as appropriate.

So in your `function navigation` rather than adding and removing `fixed`, you would instead be setting `$('.navigation').css('top', window_top - div_top)`. (remember, the `div.navigation` has to be `position:relative` first)